# Can't connect to MongoDB in docker container via hostname

Tags: c#, mongodb, docker

I am working on a small personal project and recently switched from PostgreSQL to MongoDB. Mongo is running in a docker container, and when running my API locally, everything works fine. However, when I try to run my API in docker, the only way I can get it to connect successfully to Mongo is by using my local network IP for the connection string. When I try to connect via hostname (either `host.docker.internal` or the mongo container name `mongo`), it fails to connect. I've confirmed that both `curl host.docker.internal:27017` and `curl mongo:27017` succeed.

In other words, The connection string is formatted as `mongodb://user:pwd@host/database`. When running locally, this works with `host = "localhost"`, and it works in docker with `host = "my.local.ip"`, but not with `host = "host.docker.internal"` or `host = "mongo"`.

Connecting:

```cs
var mongoClient = new MongoClient(
                $"mongodb://{dbCreds.Username}:{dbCreds.Password}@{dbCreds.Host}/{dbCreds.Database}");
```

docker_compose.yaml:

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
    homenotify.api:
        build: ./HomeNotify.API
        ports:
            - '5000:80'
        networks:
            - api
            - db
        environment:
            - GOOGLE_CREDENTIAL=service_account_key.json
            - DB_CREDENTIALS=db_credentials_docker.json
networks:
    api:
        name: api
        driver: bridge
    db:
        name: db
        external: true
```

Stack trace:

```
Unhandled exception. System.TimeoutException: A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "Automatic", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/mongo:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/mongo:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.

---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Sockets on this platform are invalid for use after a failed connection attempt.

at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ThrowMultiConnectNotSupported()

at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnect(String host, Int32 port, AsyncCallback requestCallback, Object state)

at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.ConnectAsync(Socket socket, EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.CreateStreamAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Comment: Have you tried defining db as a bridge network?

Comment: It is, it's just in a different yaml that has mongodb and mongo Express in it. Different yamls because I don't want to have to take the DB down every time I rebuild the API. And `curl mongo:27017` works, just not the actual connection.

Comment: curl works from inside the API-container?

Comment: Yes, inside the API container. I can also `ping homenotify.api` from the mongo express container (mongo doesn't have ping or curl installed).

Comment: Hmm, weird. Can you confirm that your credentials does not contain an '@' sign?

Comment: Correct. The only thing I'm changing is the host in my connection string, my LAN ip works but host.docker.internal and mongo don't (I was using host.docker.internal with psql just fine).

Comment: You do not need two yaml files. You can restart individual services in a multi service docker-compose file using docker-compose restart <serivceName>. Same thing with docker-compose up <serviceName>.

Comment: True, but the other end goal of having it separate is to use the same mongo instance for multiple projects. And having one yaml wouldn't affect my problem of only being able to connect by ip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, dotnet has an issue with sockets not supporting hostnames on non-Windows platforms. This is why it works locally but not in docker: it's on Windows when running locally, and Linux when running in docker. This was supposedly [fixed years ago](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1736), but that's what the issue is.

Manually resolving the IP address from the hostname, and using the IP to connect instead, resolved my issue. Found the code snippet [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61383617/13506648)

```cs
dbCreds.Host = Dns.GetHostAddresses(dbCreds.Host)
                .FirstOrDefault(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)?.ToString();
```